# Syntax Error in JProperties package for Python

Tags: python

I currently installed [jproperties](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jproperties) in python using pip

```
pip install jproperties
```

[image]
However when I try to run `from jproperties import Properties`, I get the following syntax error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhishek.roy\Documents\My_Scripts\property_file_updater.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jproperties.Properties
  File "C:\Users\abhishek.roy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\jproperties.py", line 131
    ord(u"\r"): ur"\r",
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am unable to figure out the Syntax Error in **jproperties.py** *Line 131*. Below are the lines 129-134 from jproperties.py

```
# Do simple whitespace substitutions.
trans_dict = {
    ord(u"\r"): ur"\r",
    ord(u"\n"): ur"\n",
    ord(u"\f"): ur"\f"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JProperties package is only compatible with Python 2, while you appear to be using Python 3.6.

Per the package information in the link you provided:

> jProperties is a Java Property file parser and writer for Python 2

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Can you suggest a properties parser for Python 3?

Comment: @AbhishekRoy try using py2to3 to convert this package

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Worked like a charm. Thanks.